# Number theory-Modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Prove that

(a)  A number is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3.

(c)  The number 100x+ 10y+zis divisible by 11 if 11|x−y+z.(e.g.  11|528)

I am really bad at proving something please help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: You won't get any better without effort.